# document.ready being fired twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I have the following Javscript at the the top of a partial view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('@Model.Course.CompletionTypeID');
    $('#Submit').live('click', function () {
        if ('@Model.Course.CompletionTypeID' == 2 || '@Model.Course.CompletionTypeID' == 3) {
            alert("IN THE LOOP");
            var fullURL = document.URL;
            fullURL = fullURL.replace("#", "");
            var courseID = fullURL.split('courseID=');
            var courseID = courseID[1];

            var postData = { 'courseID': courseID };
            $.post('/Course/FinishSurvey/', postData, function (data) {
                alert("COOL");
                $('#finishDiv').hide();
                $('#finishCompleteDiv').show();
                alert("COOL COOL");
                document.getElementById("FinishButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("LaunchButton").style.visibility = "visible";
            });
        }
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

    });
});
</script>
```

Upon clicking the 'Submit' button I get the alert stating "IN THE LOOP" so I have successfully entered the loop but it then errors out at the top if statement because for some reason I cant work out the post method does not seem to be getting hit despite the code being copied from a working page. it errors out on the following line:

```
 if ('@Model.Course.CompletionTypeID' == 2 || '@Model.Course.CompletionTypeID' == 3) {
```

even though it has already entered this loop having found a value for this model variable. If I then press F5 on the debug it is moving to the Course/FinishSurvey controller method but I cannot get to this point without pressing F5. Can anyone tell me if there is anything I am doing wrong from what you can see, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is indicating to you that document.ready is being fired twice?

Comment: Do you really need to use `live`? what jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you declare your event.

```
$('#Submit').live('click', function () {
```

should be:

```
$('#Submit').live('click', function (event) {
```

However, I would do this instead:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // your ajax code
});
```

Comment: It will be soon. It is deprecated.

Comment: Tried this still getting the same thing, what would cause this to happen?

Comment: No @vlad, it's not deprecated it's dead. since version 1.9.